# How enable omemo on Ejabberd 16.09-4 Debian9?

Tags: android, ejabberd, omemo

Is it possible (and eventually how) to enable OMEMO comunications for Ejabberd 16.09-4 on a Linux box Debian9?

I would like to enable OMEMO for using this feature on Android Conversation.

I've seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/939108/ejabberd-and-conversations-using-omemo) that need to enable:

```
force_node_config:
```

but this code option is not present on Ejabberd 16.09-4 config.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* a forced node configuration (there is by the way some config options missing. I assume you are talking about [this](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/815b95c6233b13af5efa7081d0cc1df7eb590f45)).

If your users are adding their chat partners to the contact list (roster), OMEMO works out of the box even without the forced whitelist access model. Overriding the node configuration only comes in handy if you want to enable OMEMO between users that don't have each other added to their contact lists.